# Problema con query en SQL

Tags: sql

buen día, soy principiante en sql, y hoy se me presentó un problema.
Tengo una tabla con registros que obtengo de un reloj checador, donde indica el horario en que un trabajador registro su entrada o salida, la cual tiene los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es hacer un query que tome esas checadas y determine cual es la menor de ellas y cual es la mayor para así determinar su entrada y salida y las demás no las tome en cuenta.

y devuelva algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, muchas gracias...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo??? si no, lee sobre group by y las funciones max y min...

Comment: Y siempre que hagas preguntas sobre sql, aclara para que base de datos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponemos que tu tabla se llama "usuarios".

Que tu tabla "usuarios" tiene dos columnas: "nombre" y "hora".

Tienes que usar las funcions "MIN()" Y "MAX()" que te devuelven el menor y mayor valor de una columna respectivamente. Si ademas usas la clausula "group by" para agrupar ese resultado por nombre de usuario, entonces obtendrías no una sino tantas rows como usuarios distintos alla cada uno con su minimo y su maximo.

Aqui puedes leer sobre estas funciones:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Entonces la query quedaría así.

```
SELECT nombre, MIN(hora) as "Entrada", MAX(hora) as "Salida" from usuarios group by nombre;
```

Comment: Cuando la pregunta no aclara que se intento, en general tratamos de esperar a ver que hizo OP para poder corregirlo.. aunque tu respuesta es correcta, no explica nada de nada.. solo resuelve el problema...

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Sería mejor recomendar enlaces de doc oficial en lugar de w3...